# How to determine your ground is connected to earth

Tags: ground, grounding, testing, earth

I have a tester at a remote (international) site that has been having test failures.  We traced the problem to a noise issue.

[image: noise]

We were investigating the noise issues with the test/tester and discovered that the location the tester was installed did not have a grounded electrical service and believe that was the issue.
Also, initially the ground was floating and the AC neutral was not grounded so the EMI caps in the instruments were pulling the ground (and the cabinet) to a high enough voltage that they were noticing it when they touched the cabinet - OUCH!!

[image: shocking]

So, here is my question:
Say they say the "fixed" the grounding issue but they are still having test failures.
Assuming we don't have access to a known (or at least trusted) earth ground, what measurement could I have them do that would provide a clear indication that the chassis ground had a low impedance connection to earth?

[image: grounding]

Comment: Your final diagram shows an earth on the supply transformer. Given your description that seems a rather bold assumption.

Comment: "we don't have access to a known (or at least trusted) earth ground". Do you have access to **any** grounding rod? If so, does a clamp ammeter show current through it?

Comment: If a shock can be felt when touching the cabinet, what ELSE was the victim touching?   In a well-constructed building, all architectural metal (including reinforcement in concrete, and plumbing) has ground bonding.

Comment: mark, Just some thoughts. No answers. First, the NEC code spends a lot of time on remote structures (barns, horse yards, etc.) and grounding issues. It's non-trivial to say the least. Livestock like horses with 4 feet on the ground would get shocked coming into a grounded concrete slab, for example. There are mitigation ideas they suggest which take some thought and aren't necessarily obvious. Worth some reading. Another is that you may need to know what else is going on nearby the site -- like "Is there a smelter, nearby?" Such nearby large circulating currents can present problems.

Comment: Is the ground particularly dry ?  I've heard of situations where the grounding stake is too dry in the soil, for a good connection to earth.   Has this ever worked properly or has this site always had "weirdness" ?

Comment: One thing I do know about a good earth ground is that it is a VERY stable reference.  The earth is SO LARGE there is not realistic way to change it's electrostatic potential.  This concept is part of how capacitance touch screens work.  Based on that, I was thinking there might be some way to take advantage of that to make a measurement that could be used to qualify the ground.

Comment: The last diagram was something quick, it is not accurate. We really don't know how the site is wired and travelling there is problematic.  Regarding NEC, the equipment is at an international vendor location with very lax codes. They said there are very few location in their factory that have grounding.